# Highcharts & jQuery: add a mark by clicking with Shift key pressed, then process on release

Tags: jquery, highcharts, jquery-events

I am working with Meteor (means jQuery ok) and Highcharts.

For data analysis purposes, users need to be able to set markers between two initial markers by clicking on the chart. I want them to be able do that as long as shift key is hold down. Here the algo:

```
When user click on the chart,
__ if it is the first marker, then add a opening flag;
__ if shift key is hold, then
__ __ **while** Shift key is hold, add a cutting flag;
>>>>    when Shift key is up, *process data*, **<<<< BUT WITHOUT CLICKING!**
__ add a closing flag and *process data*.
```

The **WHITOUT CLICKING** is killing me as it means that a `keyup` event handler should wrap the click event. I don't know how, *in the Highcharts events context*, bind those two events.

Here a jsFiddle to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/hsolatges/65ydL2o4/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

- you create an event to catch `keydown`. If it is `shift` key code, you set a reactive variable to true. Don't use a session variable, [get reactive dict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) if you can. (you add `var pageSession = new ReactiveDict();` at the beginning of your js file)
- you create an event to catch `keyup`. If it is `shift` key code, you set the reactive var to false
- you create a click event handler on your chart and you check the state of you reactive variable to do your stuff.

here is an example of the keydown event:

```
Template.YourTemplate.events({
"keydown .yourGraph": function(e, t) {
    if (e.which===16) {
        pageSession.set("ShiftPressed", true);  
    }
 }   
});
```

Comment: Ok, here what I have done so far. In shared code area:
`var pageSession = new ReactiveDict();
pageSession.set('shiftKey', false);`

Then on client side
`'keydown': function(event) {
      if(event.which === 16) {
        pageSession.set('shiftKey', true);
        console.log(pageSession.get('shiftKey'));
      }
    },
    'keyup': function() {
      if(event.which === 16) {
        pageSession.set('shiftKey', false);
        console.log(pageSession.get('shiftKey'));
        // Process data
      }
    }`
It works so far.

**But what did you advise me not to use Session variables?**

Comment: Only because you don't need these variables beyond your actual template. This is just a good practice: your pageSession scope is current page only.

Comment: I see... Thanks for your help. But still, in this context of Highcharts, I get some difficulties to do what I want. I am not mastering yet JS function declaration and I keep getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined` whatever I am trying.

I know (more guessing...) that this is because functions are declared before `$('#chart-placeholder').highcharts();` has been done. But how can I do that properly? There is my project: http://meteorpad.com/pad/6NDneym2qEW7pF9JM/ClearChrom if you have some time to spare.

Thanks! :)

Comment: I see 2 possibilities: either your object property `series` is not called properly (use console.log to see if it is the case), either you try to invoke it before you instantiated the object it belongs to. You should wrap some of your code in `Template.main.rendered = function(){ //your code}`. It allows you to make sure all the DOM objects are ready (in case you try to attach your object too soon to a DOM element).

Comment: FYI you can also use `created` instead if you need to load something *before* the page is rendered. Whatever your problem is, add lots of `console.logs` in the process and try to see if it is in the expected order (assuming you call properly your object property)

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help. It is working pretty nice so far! Have a nice day! :)